# Do i need an ATAS certificate for a short term research in UK?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, paperwork

Do i need an ATAS certificate for a short term research (10 weeks) course in physics at Loughborough University, UK? [nationality: Indian]

Comment: What is an ATAS certificate?

Comment: That will probably depend on what you're researching. The University should be able to advise.

Comment: @Traveller [Academic Technology Approval Scheme](https://www.ukuni.net/articles/what-atas-certificate)

Comment: Is the course study or research? If the research you propose to undertake falls within the activities permitted under the Visitor rules https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility, there is no mention of an ATAS in the list of required documents https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf#page3

Comment: @Traveller I am applying for a student VISA...so i dont think that might be on the list that you mentioned. The course mode is research.

Comment: @ReddHerring one of my friends visited UK last year without the ATAS certificate because it was a short-term course. I dont know if that thing is still applicable

Comment: @satyamjha I don't know either. What does the university say?

Comment: @Satyam Jha You can check if you need an ATAS certificate here https://www.academic-technology-approval.service.gov.uk/

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.

Comment: I'm sorry forgot to clarify. Upon enquiry from the college's immigration I found out that I need an ATAS certificate, independent of the duration of stay, just because CAH3 code and nationality.